# MongoDB query dates get no results

Tags: mongodb

Maintained a database called "human" with more than 300,000 results of news, but when I use the date query to get the results when the date is after 2018-01-04 it always shows 0 results.

```
> db.human.count({"crawled_time":{"$gte":new Date("2018-01-04")}})
0
> db.human.count({"crawled_time":{"$gte":new Date("2018-01-04T00:00:00.000Z")}})

0
> db.human.count({"version_created":{"$gte":new Date("2018-01-04T00:00:00.000Z")}})
0
> db.human.count({"version_created":{$gte:new Date("2018-01-04T00:00:00.000Z")}})
0
> db.human.count({"version_created":{$gte:new Date("2018-01-04T00:00:00.000Z")}})
0
> db.human.count({"version_created":{$gte:new Date("2018-01-04T00:00:00Z")}})
0
> db.human.count({"version_created":{"$gte":ISODate("2018-01-04T00:00:00.0000Z")}})
0
```

A sample of the database file json looks like this:

```
{"_id":"21adb21dc225406182f031c8e67699cc","_class":"com.pats.reuters.pojo.NewsData","alt_id":"nWGB30349","audiences":["NP:MNI"],"body":"ISSUER: City of Spencer, IA\nAMOUNT: $1,500,000\nDESCRIPTION: General Obligation Corporate Purpose Bonds, Series 2018\n------------------------------------------------------------------------\nSELLING: Feb 5  TIME: 11:00 AM., EST\nFINANCIAL ADVISOR: PFM Fin Advisors\n------------------------------------------------------------------------\n    ","first_created":"2018-01-30T06:12:05.000Z","headline":"SEALED BIDS: City of Spencer, IA, $1.5M  Ult G.O. On Feb 5","instances_of":[],"language":"en","message_type":2,"mime_type":"text/plain","provider":"NS:RTRS","pub_status":"stat:usable","subjects":["A:R","E:T","E:5I","E:S","A:95","A:85","M:1QD","N2:MUNI","N2:PS1","N2:SL1","N2:CM1","N2:IA1","N2:GOS"],"takeSequence":1,"urgency":3,"version_created":"2018-01-30T06:12:05.000Z","source_id":"WGB30349__180130279kIQIcAh81BiGVmb/Js54Wg3naQC6GXEu9+H","crawled_time":"2018-01-30 14:12:05"}
{"_id":"8ba08c4af9464c6b23cc508645d5bf03","_class":"com.pats.reuters.pojo.NewsData","alt_id":"nWGB3034a","audiences":["NP:MNI"],"body":"ISSUER: City of Long Branch, NJ\nAMOUNT: $31,629,415\nDESCRIPTION: Bond Anticipation Notes, Consisting of $22,629,415 Bond Anticipation Notes, Series 2018A and\n------------------------------------------------------------------------\nSELLING: Feb 1  TIME: 11:30 AM., EST\nFINANCIAL ADVISOR: N.A.\n------------------------------------------------------------------------\n    ","first_created":"2018-01-30T06:12:06.000Z","headline":"SEALED BIDS: City of Long Branch, NJ, $31.629M  Ult G.O. On Feb 1","instances_of":[],"language":"en","message_type":2,"mime_type":"text/plain","provider":"NS:RTRS","pub_status":"stat:usable","subjects":["G:6J","A:R","E:T","E:5I","E:S","A:9M","E:U","M:1QD","N2:US","N2:MUNI","N2:PS1","N2:SL1","N2:CM1","N2:NJ1","N2:NT1"],"takeSequence":1,"urgency":3,"version_created":"2018-01-30T06:12:06.000Z","source_id":"WGB3034a__1801302ksv4Iy0zSP5cscas0FlZgu1TpQ4Zh25VKCtSt","crawled_time":"2018-01-30 14:12:06"}
{"_id":"537f70076ef056c9a43d30c89500353a","_class":"com.pats.reuters.pojo.NewsData","alt_id":"nWGB3034b","audiences":["NP:MNI"],"body":"ISSUER: Independent School District No. 76 of Canadian County (Calumet), OK\nAMOUNT: $1,630,000\nDESCRIPTION: Combined Purpose Bonds of 2018\n------------------------------------------------------------------------\nSELLING: Feb 12 TIME: 05:00 PM., EST\nFINANCIAL ADVISOR: Stephen H. McDonald\n------------------------------------------------------------------------\n    ","first_created":"2018-01-30T06:12:07.000Z","headline":"SEALED BIDS: Independent School District No. 76 of Canadian County (Calumet), OK, $1.63M  Ult G.O. On Feb 12","instances_of":[],"language":"en","message_type":2,"mime_type":"text/plain","provider":"NS:RTRS","pub_status":"stat:usable","subjects":["A:R","E:T","E:5I","E:S","A:9R","M:1QD","N2:MUNI","N2:PS1","N2:SL1","N2:CM1","N2:OK1"],"takeSequence":1,"urgency":3,"version_created":"2018-01-30T06:12:07.000Z","source_id":"WGB3034b__1801302ev7DqID2Wr/BAJHrC/plpNKBQhrfuHBnlSldz","crawled_time":"2018-01-30 14:12:07"}
```

Comment: what is the type of `crawled_time` and `version_created`?

Comment: Is there a mongodb command and code to check the type?

Comment: You can check with any GUI like compass or robomonogo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your field value is not a date object. It is a string. So you can't use `new Date("2018-01-04")`. Use the below query.

```
  db.human.count({"crawled_time":{"$gte":"2018-01-04"}})

  db.human.count({"version_created":{"$gte":"2018-01-04"}})
```